# How do I make sentence with charge?

Tags: american-english

I want to make sentence with charge.
but I'm not sure as to sentence structure with charge.

For example.
Is something just charge of something?
Can I make like this?
If I wrong please let me know about it.

And I want to know the case of sample without 'of' at above example.

UPDATE: 
If I want to ask as to who's responsibillty? How do I do?

Comment: Can you update your question with more context?  What are you trying to say?

Comment: The word _charge_ is a **very** flexible word in English. It can be used as a verb or a noun, and has more than [30 meanings](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/charge), and they are not all used the same way. You'll need to provide more details to get more accurate answers. Explain exactly what you are trying to say (not just something charge of something), and we can help you express it in the right way.

Comment: Hmm I don't understand how can't you catch the point at question. It was just about verb. Maybe can't I make point of question?

Comment: Which verb? _The armies charged at each other. The man charged his cell phone. The woman was charged with murder._ Those sentences all use the verb _charge_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is responsible for something (say, a project, or a child), we usually use the expression ***in charge (of)***. For example:

> David is **in charge of** the parts department.
>
> "Remember, Tommy, while we are gone the babysitter **in charge**."

The first sentence means David manages the parts department. The second sentence means Tommy is expected to mind (or obey) the babysitter while his parents are gone.

Comment: In second text,Why you do not use 'of'  at in charge of?

Comment: I get it. If there are need some explain then the of used like first sentence. But if no need to explain then the of no needed that. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's it. When it's at the end of the sentence, and the context makes it clear, you can simply end with "in charge". "While we are gone, the babysitter is in charge (of you, of the house, etc.)"

Comment: Related: Perhaps one of the most infamous uses of "in charge" in modern American history, by [Al Haig](http://adst.org/2014/03/al-haig-and-the-reagan-assassination-attempt-im-in-charge-here/).

Comment: Did you mean there is another way instead use"in charge"?

Comment: @Carter - I mean that one can say "I'm in charge of this" or "He's in charge here." In that context, words like _this_ and _here_ can refer to something as small as a room or as big as a nation.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand your last clasuese.